# Authentication using Email and resulted routing problems

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-registration, django-login

I'm trying to Authenticate users by their emails instead of username.

I'm using `django-userena` and by using its Docs,etc. I set almost anything that is needed. Something like : `USERENA_WITHOUT_USERNAMES = True` in its setting, etc.

But after signing up, I've faced a chain of problems. like trying to pass my username in the url for authentication, signup completion problems, etc.

I changed some view functions that need username as an argument, but this method neither solved my problem , nor is a correct (and maybe secure) way to do it.

for instance, by routing to this URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/complete/` (after `$ ./manage.py check_permissions` ) I get this error:

```
global name 'username' is not defined
/userena/views.py in directto_user_template
user = get_object_or_404(User, username_iexact=username)
```

Is there anything that I'm missing ??

**UPDATE:** 
Here is the output that I get:

> Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'userena_activate'
>   with arguments '('xyz@xyz.com',
>   '70b60d1d97015e03ba8d57f31e4c7ff14d6ab753')' and keyword arguments
>   '{}' not found.

It's clear that userena tries to the email as username with URL :

> userena/templates/userena/emails/activation_email_message.txt, error at line 8

```
1   {% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}
2   {% if not without_usernames %}{% blocktrans with user.username as username %}Dear {{ username }},{% endblocktrans %}
3   {% endif %}
4   {% blocktrans with site.name as site %}Thank you for signing up at {{ site }}.{% endblocktrans %}
5   
6   {% trans "To activate your account you should click on the link below:" %}
7   
8   {{ protocol }}://{{ site.domain }}{% url userena_activate user.username activation_key %}
9   
10  {% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}
11  
12  {% trans "Sincerely" %},
13  {{ site.name }}
14  {% endautoescape %}
```

**UPDATE 2:** 
Alright . by reading the source code for `SignupFormOnlyEmail` class form, it says that a random username is generated automatically.

```
class SignupFormOnlyEmail(SignupForm):
    """
    Form for creating a new user account but not needing a username.

    This form is an adaptation of :class:`SignupForm`. It's used when
    ``USERENA_WITHOUT_USERNAME`` setting is set to ``True``. And thus the user
    is not asked to supply an username, but one is generated for them. The user
    can than keep sign in by using their email.

    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupFormOnlyEmail, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        del self.fields['username']

    def save(self):
        """ Generate a random username before falling back to parent signup form """
        while True:
            username = sha_constructor(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
            try:
                User.objects.get(username__iexact=username)
            except User.DoesNotExist: break

        self.cleaned_data['username'] = username
        return super(SignupFormOnlyEmail, self).save()
```

**UPDATE :**

I finally solved the problem. I was also using `django-email-as-username` beside to `django-userena`. This was the cause of my problem. Apparently, they have some conflicts. WATCH OUT

Comment: error message says everything: variable 'username' is not defined. Post code of your views.py, pls

Comment: The code exists in its [Github](http://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/views.py) . I will update th post with more info .. for example, look at the line 142, "activate" function  ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined url route `userena_activate` with keyword arguments (`username` and `activation_key`), but you call it just with arguments, change template to keyword arguments:

```
{% url userena_activate username=user.username activation_key=activation_key %}
```

edit due to comment:

I'm not sure if I understand your problem corectly, but I think there's a problem elsewhere. Yours error message says:

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'userena_activate' with arguments '('xyz@xyz.com', '70b60d1d97015e03ba8d57f31e4c7ff14d6ab753')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

It seems you pass valid arguments to function, but you pass them wrong way. URL route in urls.py is defined in a way to expect `kwargs`, but you pass just `args`, which mismatch its definition. That is why you get this error message. Simple pass arguments as `kwargs` (that means each argument is passed with its name and value as showed above).

urls.py difference between argument and keyword argument:

```
url(r'^(?P<username>[\.\w]+)/activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$', userena_views.activate, name='userena_activate'),
         ^ this is _keyword argument_ 'username', expects value with argument value AND name
```

and

```
url(r'^page/(.*)/$', userena_views.ProfileListView.as_view(), name='userena_profile_list_paginated'),
            ^ this is argument, expects only value, not argument name
```

Comment: you are right.. I don't have username, that's why I said a chain of problems... If I edit and remove username from view/urls/templates, etc, then  I got stuck in next views and urls as well ... Do you recommend to remove "all" of username fields within the code base ?? Or there is a better and cleaner way ?

Comment: addition: you have username (at least you have it declared). I bet if you add it into template output ({{ user.username }}), you will see it, so you will see it is not the real problem.

Comment: Yes, it's been produced randomly. OK, you suggest _Simple pass arguments as kwargs_ .. yes, you are right, but the relevant URL for 'userena_activate', accepts "kwargs". So why it complains ? Sorry for asking too much questions, This is so vital for me ..

Comment: If you mean 'function accepts kwargs' as 'function expects kwargs', then I agree. If you mean 'function accepts kwargs' as 'I already pass kwargs to function', then no. Let's take 'activation_email_message.txt' as an example, line 8 looks like this: `{% url userena_activate user.username activation_key %}`. These are just `args`. `Kwargs` looks this way: `}{% url userena_activate username=user.username activation_key=activation_key %}`. Do you see the difference? `Kwargs` have there `argument name` as well.

Comment: Yes,sure I know. I changed to `{% url userena_activate username=user.username activation_key=activation_key %}`. heh .. Now it complains on `Reverse for 'userena_activate' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'username': 'lap10@lap.com', 'activation_key': 'c53fc7756b685d5c1557e9cd45a8dda809503ab0'}' not found.` it tries to put the email as username as its view function expects.. I'm so lost on this

Comment: maybe because this regexp: `(?P<username>[\.\w]+)` in urls doesn't match email address, which you submit .)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13159/discussion-between-yedpodtrzitko-and-soask)

Answer (score 0):

A really simple alternative for using the email address as the username (effectively) is [django-easy-userena](https://github.com/barszczmm/django-easy-userena) - this is an upward compatible fork of Userena that adds a few nice features:

- use email address as effective user ID - generates a random numeric
  username that is hidden in forms and confirmation emails
- fewer dependencies - doesn't require django-guardian or easy-thumbnails
- terms of service agreement field is built in, displays as checkbox

I've had good results with this - installation was manual for some reason (copy userena dir to site-packages) but it worked without hassles.

I like the overall Userena approach, but easy-userena is a better fit for what I need.